# Trying to understand reference of and address of in pointers

Tags: c

Given below code why would  a and b values change..P1 and p2 are storing address of a and b,why would a and b change when p1 and p2 are changed

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{

//&a stores address
//*p1 is a pointer

int a = 5, b = 10;
 int *p1, *p2;  //p1 and p2 are 2 pointers which can store int addressses

 p1 = &a;  //now p1 and p2 stores address of a and b
 p2 = &b; 



  printf("p1 storing address of a  = %d\n", *p1); 
 printf("p2 storing address of  b = %d\n", *p2);

 *p1=30;  
 *p2=40;

 printf("p1 assigning values to p1 pointer = %d\n", *p1); 
 printf("p2 assigning values to p2 pointer= %d\n", *p2);



 printf("a whose value is = %d\n", a); 
 printf("b = %d\n", b);

}
```

Comment: try to draw a schema to understand by yourself. the pointers contains the address of a variable, you can modify the space pointed by the pointer with *pointer = value;

Comment: `*p1 = 30` stores the int 30 at the memory address `p1` points to. The memory that `a` uses for its value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think things will be clearer for you if you also print the pointers themselves instead of just their contents. You can use the `%p` specifier for that.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int a = 10;
  int b = 20;
  int *p = &a;
  int *q = &b;

  printf("1) p is %p\n", p);
  printf("1) q is %p\n", q);
  printf("1) a is %d\n", a);
  printf("1) b is %d\n", b);

  p = q;

  /* At this point, I changed the value of p so that it  points to `b`
     just like `q` does. `a` and `b` are still unchanged. */ 
  printf("2) p is %p\n", p);
  printf("2) q is %p\n", q);
  printf("2) a is %d\n", a);
  printf("2) b is %d\n", b);

  *p = 30;

  /* Now that p points to `b`, dereferencing the pointer will affect `b`
     instead of `a` */
  printf("3) p is %p\n", p);
  printf("3) q is %p\n", q);
  printf("3) a is %d\n", a);
  printf("3) b is %d\n", b);
}
```

When you say `*p = something` you are assigning the memory location that `p` is pointing to (which might be `a` or `b` depending on how you set things up). On the other hand, if you do `p = q` you change the pointer itself and not the contents it was pointing to.

Comment: thanks for the great example,i keep coming to this example many times

Comment: I'm glad to know it was helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

`p1` and `p2` contain addresses of `a` and `b`. When we use `*p1=30;`
it tells the compiler to assign the value of the variable whos address is contained by `p1` as `30`

you can think it as value of address conained by `p1` to be `30`.

```
* = value at
```

and

```
& = address of
```